# Add JSON Object at specific location

Tags: json, linux, jq

Here are my two json files content:

file1.json

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.4",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-A"
    },
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.6",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-B"
    },
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.7",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-C"
    }
  ]
}
```

file2.json

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.4",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-D"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add the contents of file2.json to file1.json but after the json object : **TB1-OSC-B** i.e., second json entry. In this case the entry is present at second location but it may be present any where else aswell.
My final json file should look like this:

file3.json

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.4",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-A"
    },
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.6",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-B"
    },
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.4",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-D"
    },
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.7",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-C"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using jq version : 1.3 and I have no way to upgade it. I tried using add and =+ parameters provided by jq. But it did not help.

Thanks in advnace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to append the object from `file2.json` to the `nodes` array it is fairly straightforward:

```
jq -s '.[0].nodes += [ .[1].nodes[0] ] | .[0]' file1.json file2.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.4",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-A"
    },
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.6",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-B"
    },
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.7",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-C"
    },
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.4",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-D"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, because you want to insert the object, it becomes more tricky, as `jq` AFAIK does not support insertion into arrays, only prepending and appending.

Below is a rather convoluted example of how to do this by splicing it in:

*parse.jq*

```
# Find the desired index and store it as $n
(.[0].nodes | map(.name == "TB1-OSC-B") | index(true)) as $n   |

# Splice the object from the second file  into the first
.[0].nodes =   .[0].nodes[0:($n|tonumber+1)]   +
             [ .[1].nodes[0] ]                 +
               .[0].nodes[($n|tonumber+1):(.[0].nodes|length)] |

# Only output the now modified object from the first file 
.[0]
```

Run it like this:

```
jq -sf parse.jq file1.json file2.json
```

Output in this case:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.4",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-A"
    },
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.6",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-B"
    },
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.4",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-D"
    },
    {
      "pm_addr": "192.100.0.7",
      "name": "TB1-OSC-C"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: OP says they have `jq-1.3`, not sure `index(true)` will be available as a built-in there. Other way could be `jq '.nodes | to_entries[] | select(.value.name == "TB1-OSC-B").key'` but again not sure `to_entries[]` is supported in the OP's version

Comment: @Inian: I checked out version 1.3 and verified that it works there

Comment: I'm not sure that's preferable, but you can merge your two `jq` commands into one if you want : https://jqplay.org/s/IW3X9Gca7c

Comment: @ Thor, Inian and Aaron thanks for your solutions..I have merged all your answers into one line command and its working as I expected

Comment: @Inian: Nice, I couldn't quite get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Thor: I meant that piece of code an alternate for getting the index alone, in case `index(true)` is not available - https://jqplay.org/s/VAm7ZtUB02

Answer (score 2):

The key to a clear and maintainable solution is having suitable utility functions.

### Utility functions for jq 1.3

```
def insert_at(i; x): .[:i] + [x] + .[i:];

def indicesof(f):
  . as $in
  | range(0;length) | select( $in[.] | f );

def insert_after(f; x):
  [indicesof(f)] as $ix
  | if ($ix|length) > 0
    then insert_at($ix[0]+1; x) 
    else . end;
```

### Utility functions for jq 1.4 or later

jq 1.4 allows a more efficient solution, courtesy of `first/1`:

```
def insert_at($i; $x): .[:$i] + [$x] + .[$i:];

def indicesof(f):
  . as $in
  | range(0;length) | select( $in[.] | f );

def insert_after(f; $x):
  (first(indicesof(f)) // null) as $i
  | if $i then insert_at($i + 1; $x) else . end;
```

### Solution

With these utility functions, solutions to the given problem can be expressed directly. For example, assuming an invocation along the lines of:

```
jq -s -f merge.jq file1.json file2.json
```

```
.[1].nodes[0] as $file2
| .[0]
| .nodes |= insert_after(.name == "TB1-OSC-B"; $file2)
```

This can easily be modified depending on the detailed requirements.